# Can someone please interpret this reputation update for me?

Tags: support, reputation, top-bar

The recent achievements menu's caption in the top bar just told me I had 10 new rep. However, when opened it couldn't deliver:

[image]

Where the heck did it take that green +10 from?

Comment: Did you get any extra rep?

Comment: Might have been a retracted upvote.

Comment: @Tijesunimi: _???_

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian: Not that I knew of.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to group rep from all sites into a single indicator.

Comment: @bjb568 - why? And what's your better alternative, given that the drop-down gives you the breakdown?

Comment: @Oded I'm not sure. Maybe a single number of rep changes? Maybe a "from 2 sites" indicator of some sort? (Hard to do without cluttering) Unsigned rep change number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely explanation:

- An answer got upvoted
- You got notified
- That answer got un-upvoted (with the above events being in close succession)
- No notification for that (and no removal of current notification, 'cause we don't do that)

Symptoms:

You see +10 notification, but nothing for it (no actual rep gain, no corresponding rep entries anywhere else).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!